# How do I get VirtualBox to run on Arch?

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-modules, linux-headers

When I try to start up a Windows 7 VM, I get 2 popup error windows. The first says:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows7Box.
>
> The virtual machine 'Windows7Box' has terminated unexpectedly during
> startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: MachineWrap
> Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

The second says:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
> the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
> you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
> more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
> support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

I have run that, and gotten the following:

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig 
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

That's where I'm stuck. Yay says my `linux-headers` package is up-to-date, and I'm not sure how to sign kernel modules or what that means.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What kernel version are you running? If it's the latest-and-greatest - v5.16.7 as of this post - try using the LTS kernel.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I'm running 5.13.13

Comment: On my (2) Arch systems, this kernel does not exist. What does `yay -Qs linux-headers` and `lsb_release -ds` (use `grep ^ID= /etc/os-release | cut -d'=' -f2` if **lsb_release** is not installed) return?